# Cause of Relay Coil to stop working ( No resistance) can it be fixed?

Tags: relay

[image: photo of relay]

Reason for my strand relays HLR6100-1ATJCB 240VAC to break and stop working? The Coil resistance before using was 9.0M ohms. It doesn't last long. Can the coil be fixed? The relay is connected to Strand C16 RCBO. Is the RCBO suppose to protect the relay? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The coil should be much lower than 9M, 9K DC resistance is plausible.

It is a power relay and will wear out in use, rating is 100,000 operations only, however the coil should not fail (go open) under normal conditions.

If the relay is exposed to corrosive environmental conditions such failures can occur.

Comment: we use the relay in our theater with well ventilated environment and in Air-conditioned but your right as the relay were already at least 6 years old and they are starting to wear out.

Comment: Sounds pretty good for what looks like a Chinese copy of a Japanese contactor. So you can replace them and relax for another 5 years or so. Life is predictable in terms of number of operations so if you have a number that are operating a similar number of times they will tend to fail at roughly the same time, like the old-fashioned halogen incandescent headlamps on a car.